# How can I set up SSH on Linux to log in password-less?

Tags: ssh, authentication

My Raspberry Pi is running the default Debian image and has SSH enabled. I log into my Pi as follows:

```
ssh pi@<IP-address-of-my-Pi>
```

I have to enter my password every time. Can I somehow make my Pi accept log ins from my local machine? I am running Fedora Linux.

Comment: It's a question specific to users or developers (interacting via SSH-clients) of the Raspberry Pi (used as an SSH-Server), so it should be OK to ask, if I interpret the [FAQ](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) correctly.

Comment: We've come to a consensus that if you could not tell if a question is about the Raspberry Pi if all references to it is removed, then it is off-topic. We also discuss questions before deciding that they are better off closed in [the official chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3748/the-bakery). Feel free to join in if you have a question!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can automate the authentication with your Raspberry Pi using SSH.

As prerequisites the following is required:

- You have [enabled SSH on the Pi](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/624/114).
- You know your Pi's IP Address.

### Linux

Under Linux you can install SSH via you package manager, generate a keypair using `ssh-keygen`, copy the key to the Pi using `ssh-copy-id` and test using `ssh`.

#### Install SSH on Linux

Most Linux distributions come with an SSH-client preinstalled. If you should for some reason not have one, install it using your package manager:

For RPM-based Linux distributions (eg. Fedora and Suse):

```
sudo yum install ssh
```

For DEB-based Linux distributions (eg. Debian and Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install ssh
```

#### Generate a Keypair on Linux

First, you will need a public/private keypair. So if you don't have one, run the following command to generate a keypair with the default settings.

```
$ ssh-keygen
generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa):
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
24:55:ee:67:83:72:82:55:5f:b9:b4:09:2a:fa:56:a1 user@client.local
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|                 |
|                 |
|         +    .  |
|        S    E   |
|         .  + +  |
|          .o . o.|
|         o.oo. oo|
|          ==o.BO+|
+-----------------+
```

#### Copy the Public Key to the Pi on Linux

Secondly, you will need to copy the generated public key to the machine you want to log to without a password. So, run the following command on the machine and as the user, you want to be able to access the Pi:

```
$ ssh-copy-id pi@<IP-address-of-your-Pi>
Password:
Now try logging into the machine, with "ssh 'pi@<IP-address-of-your-Pi>'", and check in:
  .ssh/authorized_keys
to make sure we haven't added extra keys that you weren't expecting.
```

#### SSH into the Pi on Linux

Finally, log in using SSH, to verify that no password is requested:

```
$ ssh pi@<IP-address-of-your-Pi>
```

Comment: Maybe you are right. That should be an own question, thought. I will create one if it doesn't exist and link it here.

Comment: I've added the explanation on how to generate a key, its waiting for peer review

Comment: @bngtlrs you may want to clarify that these instructions don't work on a Windows PC and ideally explain how to do this froma PC.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I have no clean solution for windows. Maybe I should make clearer, that the question is Linux-specific and someone else should care about windows in another question.

Comment: @bngtlrs If I get a chance tomorrow I will post an answer for the windows crowd if you don't mind alternatively I could make an edit to your post for your review and approval.

Comment: @SteveRobillard That would be great. We could then reformulate the question to be operating-system-agnostic and build an generic answer.

Comment: For windows [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/), [Pageant and PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) are the obvious choices.

Comment: Also, it is good practice to tidy up (delete) comments after they are no longer relevant (refer to a suggestion or question which has been addressed or answered in an edit to the answer).

Comment: **PLEASE** make sure that the `~/.ssh` directory has 700 permissions! Otherwise your security is worthless.

Comment: I suspect 700 to be the default permissions when installing SSH. If that is the case, I do not think we should advise to double check it. Also all wiki pages I found on SSH are not mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on the files you're trying to copy to make sure the user you're logging in as over ssh has permission to read them.

Comment: The OPs issue is with logins, not copying files...

Comment: Yes, my question was about copying my id. You, Joe, are in principle right about [that permissions can cause issues when trying to log in](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Keys#line-143), but that should be handled in another Q&A.