# SCP without password prompt using different username

Tags: linux, ssh, users, scp

I have 2 servers, `Server1` and `Server2`.  On `Server1` I have a user named `user1`. On `Server2` I have the user named `user2`.

I need to be able to write a script that runs on `Server1`, which will `scp` some files to `user2@Server2`.  Is there any way to do this without prompting for a password?  I can put the password in a config file or something if necessary.

I am not able to create `user2@Server1` user by the way.

Comment: Sure... `scp` to a remote server using the same username as the local account is exactly no different than doing it with a different username. If one works, the other will work too, you just have to specify the username otherwise the default is to use the same username!

Comment: For the general question, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42674/how-can-i-set-up-ssh-on-linux-to-log-in-password-less ... actually, that's a different user too.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you want are ssh-key pairs, these create 'trusted networks' that allow for password-less authentication:

On your client (server1):

```
[user@server1]# ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/root/.ssh/id_rsa): # Hit Enter
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): # Hit Enter
Enter same passphrase again: # Hit Enter
Your identification has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

Now copy your public key to your remote server (server2):

```
ssh-copy-id user2@server2
[OR]
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user2@server2 "mkdir -p ~/.ssh \
    && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Now when you run the `scp` (or any other ssh) command you shouldn't be prompted for a password:

```
scp file user2@server2:/drop/location
```

Comment: BTW: We have a question about how to copy the key at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29386/how-do-you-copy-the-public-key-to-a-ssh-server

Comment: does trust exist if i change my pw? Or do I have to redo this??