# SSH with no password

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I have a Shell bash file that i run as sudo and it contains a file to send a ssh comand to bulk clients but it asks for the password every time and i do not what key based ssh the password is the same for all of the hostnames. i also do not whant to install any outhr software.

the clients are debian and the host ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What about ssh keys?

Comment: SSH-keys is what you want and I answered how to set them up [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/182488/82289). Instead of `scp` just `ssh`.

Comment: Is there any reason why you will not use the tools ssh give to you, neither install other software to do the work?

Comment: I´m deleting my answer here since we have given you 2 Options: `sshpass` and "key based authentication". You could even install [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) but you are just promoting a [Xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and you seems to not even care changing your mind. These are the 3 only options you have. Deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Host based authentication works without prompting passwords and installing user's pub keys**

Do only step 1 and replace `.shosts` with `.rhosts` to use `rsh` which is safe in Kerberos environment.

1 Add clients's host name and user name of a user who wants access to server.
`server$ echo '<client's hostname> <user name>' >> ~/.shosts`

2 Append client's public host keys to the server's known_hosts.
`client$ cat /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub | ssh user@server 'cat >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts'`

3 Tell server to not reverse look up client's ip to find client's host name.
`server# echo 'HostbasedUsesNameFromPacketOnly yes' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

4 Ask server not to ignore .shosts file.
`server# echo 'IgnoreRhosts no' >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
`server# service sshd reload`

Comment: "i do not what key based ssh the" - Unfortunately, this guy does not want a key based authentication too...